# Problem with citation and bibliography-keyword cited instead of author-year/number

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

For weeks I have been trying to find a solution to my problem but ending without any :-(.
I am using LaTeX for my thesis and I have a problem with the citations/references in text and bibliography list. I tried a ton of option and what I get is:

1. either a problem that ends with question marks (?) throughout the text (no matter of running `latex-bibtex-latex-latex` sequence), or
2. the citation in text is neither a number nor author-year but LaTeX cites my keyword (or citekey)

I tried using the following

```
\usepackage[round, authoryear, colon]{natbib}

\label{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{alpha} %or {apalike} 
\bibliography{Bibliography-1} %Bibliography-1 is the bib file with the references 

*while ad 2 I have this commands*
\PassOptionsToPackage{
        natbib=true,
        style=authoryear-comp,
        hyperref=true,
        backend=biber,
        maxbibnames=99,
        firstinits=true,
        uniquename=init,
        maxcitenames=2,
        parentracker=true,
        url=false,
        doi=false,
        isbn=false,
        eprint=false,
        backref=true,
            }   {biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\label{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{alpha} %or {apalike} 
\bibliography{Bibliography-1} %Bibliography-1 is the bib file with the references
```

I really tried a number of options, but I obviously miss a package or something. What I would like to have is an author-year citing style in the text (I used the commands `\citet` and `\citep` mostly) and an APA formatted bibliography.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you literally using all of that? Why do you repeat the first three lines later?

You cannot use natbib and biblatex together. One is for bibtex. The other is biblatex. If you need biblatex and you don't want to change your citation setup, you can pass the natbib option and biblatex will map those commands to corresponding citation commands it knows about.

Why are you using the pass-options instead of just specifying those as options to biblatex?

In your preamble, *just* use:

```
\usepackage[% comment spaces as biblatex sometimes dislikes them a lot
        natbib=true,% just this for natbib compatibility - don't load natbib itself
        style=authoryear-comp,%
        hyperref=true,%
        backend=biber,%
        maxbibnames=99,%
        firstinits=true,%
        uniquename=init,%
        maxcitenames=2,%
        parentracker=true,%
        url=false,%
        doi=false,%
        isbn=false,%
        eprint=false,%
        backref=true,%
            ]  {biblatex}
\bibliography{Bibliography-1}
```

In your document, when you want to print the bibliography, *just* use:

```
\printbibliography
```

I strongly recommend looking at at least some of the biblatex documentation - the bit aimed at users, not all the stuff for package authors. At least to get some sense of how to set this up. You are currently trying to use both the bibtex-system-with-natbib *and* the biblatex-with-biber systems and that is bound to lead to trouble!

### Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Bibliography-1.bib}
    @book{mybook,
      author = {Author, Great},
      title = {Great Work of Fiction},
      publisher = {GreatBooks},
      year = 2039,
      location = {Great Square, Great Place}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[% comment spaces as biblatex sometimes dislikes them a lot
        natbib=true,% just this for natbib compatibility - don't load natbib itself
        style=authoryear-comp,%
        hyperref=true,%
        backend=biber,%
        maxbibnames=99,%
        firstinits=true,%
        uniquename=init,%
        maxcitenames=2,%
        parentracker=true,%
        url=false,%
        doi=false,%
        isbn=false,%
        eprint=false,%
        backref=true,%
            ]  {biblatex}
\bibliography{Bibliography-1}
\begin{document}

Here is some text \autocite[Here is a citation:][7--42]{mybook}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Running pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex -> pdflatex on the file produces:

[image: Citation and list of references]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But this still leaves the same problem intact. Writing the codes as you suggest I still get citations in text that instead of author-year cite the key (keyword) in bold font. For example in the bib file I have @article{gali03,
 Author = {Jordi Gali and Roberto Perotti},
 Journal = {NBER Working Paper},
 Number = {9773},
 Title = {Fiscal Policy and Monetary Integration in Europe},
 Year = {2003}} 
and what I get in text is eg "See gali03".I am using a template file, which is set that citations are refereed as [number], but they don't work as well :-(

Comment: Did you run biber and then run latex/pdflatex/xelatex/lualatex (whichever you are using) twice more?

Comment: Yes, a ton of times :-(. I believe I will quit and type citations manually :-(

Comment: @user43892 When you run biber, do you get any errors or warnings in the output? Can you post a Minimum Working Example which compiles and demonstrates the problem? It is hard to guess what might be wrong otherwise.

Comment: @user43892 Also, can you try the MWE I've posted and see if that works for you?

Comment: You might like to change `\bibliography{Bibliography-1}` in your `\addbibresource{Bibliography-1.bib}`, as the former is now deprecated ([see §3.6.1 of the `biblatex` documentation, p. 70](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)). Also, as far as I know, `biblatex` or better LaTeX is not particularly bothered about spaces in the package loading options.

Comment: nothing seems to work. I really do not understand. @cfr: I tried the MWE and get "Here is some text (**mybook**)" ....same as in my cases, it does not cite it properly.

Comment: I could upload a bib file and a section of a chapter if you are willing to see whether it works on your pc....

Comment: @user43892 What is biber's output if you run it on the file?

Answer (score -1):

it works now x-(!!
I saved chapters (tex), appendices (tex) and the bib file and delete the rest. I downloaded once again the thesis template and redo the latex-bibtex-latex-latex procedure and now it works!!!

I am so angry...I wasted so many nights...possibly some aux files were causing the damage... do not know. maybe you have an idea.

an hour ago I read yet a comment on a blog that says "you should delete all created aux, logs and etc files" when dealing with a similar problem as mine...

However. THANKS for all the suggestions!